# Sort first n integers in linear time and constant space

Tags: algorithm, sorting

I'm looking for a non-comparison or comparison based algorithm that can sort an array containing any permutation of the first n positive integers, which should be O(n) time complexity and O(1) space complexity.

Is there an existing algorithm that fits these specifications?

Comment: are all integers present or are there gaps?

Comment: What about simply writing all integers from 1 to n into the array?

Comment: O(n) relative to what?  A purely in-place algorithm (no side storage) would be O(1) in the size of its input...  Oh, and O(n) time or storage?

Comment: all integers are present (first n integers), no gaps

Comment: You should try wikipedia (e.g. the wonderful online resources available). You are looking for a "non-comparison sort" such as a [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort) (this isn't the only non-comparison sort). O(n) can't be achieved with *any* [comparison sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_sort) -- see the lower limits.

Comment: @Alan: ["the homework tag, like other so-called 'meta' tags, is now discouraged."](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10812)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have an array of size N with all integers from 1 to N present, you can use the following O(N) algorithm (Note: arrays are 1 based for the sake of this pseudocode so as not to introduce unnecessary complexity in explaining the algorithm):

1. Start at the first array element.
2. If its array index matches its value, go to the next one.
3. If not, swap it with the value at the array index corresponding to its value.
4. Repeat step 3, until no more swaps are necessary.
5. If not at the end of the array, go to the next array element, otherwise go to step 7
6. Go to step 2.
7. Done

Comment: @Michael Goldshteyn: if you have an array of length N which contains all the integers from 1 to N, why would you sort it at all when you could just write the integers in order into the array ?

Comment: @Mark, Perhaps he is considering the case where the integers are merely keys for the records. Here, just writing the integers in order won't help put the associated records in sorted order.

Comment: yes, I am considering the case where the integers are keys, sorry for not mentioning that

Comment: @Michael Goldshteyn the algorithm you described, does it have a name, is it "in place MSD Radix sort as Kedar Soparkar mentioned.

Comment: The MSD Radix sort is a completely different bit based algorithm. To be perfectly honest, the algorithm I described probably has a name, but I just came up with it off of the top of my head, because for an experienced developer it just seems like an obvious approach.

Comment: @fmunshi: His algorithm is a counting sort optimized for your conditions.

Answer (score 2):

[In-place MSD radix sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort#In-place_MSD_radix_sort_implementations)

Comment: That algorithm is beautiful in its simplicity. I'll have to find an excuse to use it some day.

Answer (score 1):

When you are sure that all integers are between 1 and N you can use [counting sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)

Comment: I thought he required constant space. From the wiki of counting sort - "Because it uses arrays of length k + 1 and n, the total space usage of the algorithm is also O(n + k)."